# Android - How to fix position of image

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a `LinearLayout` that has a number of text fields and an `ImageView` to the right of the `LinearLayout`. However the position of the image is never fixed and shifts depending on the content of the `TextView` fields. How do I solve this problem ? I have tried manipulating `android:layout_gravity` but that does not give me a solution. I would just like my image to dock itself at the right regardless of the content of the `TextView`s. Here is my layout file. Any pointers or a solution would be most appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

 >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/name"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_of_birth_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/date_of_birth"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_of_birth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_of_birth_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/place_of_birth"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/place_of_birth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/height_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/height"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/height"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blood_type_field"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/blood_type"  />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/blood_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </LinearLayout>

 </LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/member_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"


/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try replacing the outermost LinearLayout with a FrameLayout.  Explain if that is not the desired effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RelativeLayout in your outermost layout. You can set the image to display on the right and centre vertically.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
      >

      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="144dp"
           android:orientation="vertical"

           >

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/name_field"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/name"  />

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/name"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/date_of_birth_field"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/date_of_birth"  />

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/date_of_birth"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/place_of_birth_field"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/place_of_birth"  />

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/place_of_birth"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/height_field"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/height"  />

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/height"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

           <LinearLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/blood_type_field"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="@string/blood_type"  />

                <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/blood_type"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>

      <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/member_image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"

           />

 </RelativeLayout>
```